# Best way to check for null in PHP

Tags: php, null, memory-efficient

I want to know the best / efficient way to check for null in PHP.

```
!$var
$var === null
is_null($var)
```

Don't even know if there are more ways to check it, but I want to use the more efficient one.

Comment: I seriously doubt that there will be any noticeable difference between any  of those methods in any situation. Pick your poison! The only one that can have side effects is `!$var`, since that will give you the same result for any "falsey" value.

Answer (score -3):

I will prefer option two. But I will normally use it this way

```
null  === $var (yoda condition)
```

Yoda condition will prevent a possible mistake that you assign a value unintentionally instead of writing a conditional statement.

Frameworks like Wordpress and Symfony use yoda condition as part of their code standard.

Using is_null() function is slower since it is a function. However; the difference is really small.

reference https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions